# Angular 4 Stop subscribe when error occurs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function I am passing data which sends it to a Lambda service.  When it's successful, it returns simply 'success' in the response.. I do not need to return a value from it. Just want it to stop when there is an error..

When I simulate an error (bad data), the subscribe continues to retry over and over and over.  How can I stop the retries when I encounter an error?  I thought "error =>" handles that?

```
dataStream(dataLayer): void {
    const postBody = JSON.stringify(dataLayer);
    this.http.post(`https://api.example.com/capture`, postBody, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).subscribe(
      result => {
        if ( result === 'success') {
          this.setWindowDataLayer(dataLayer);
        }
      },
        error => {
          console.error('Failed to send dataStream: ', error);
      });
 }
```

Comment: Nothing in your code explains why anything would be retried. Unless the call to `setWindowDataLayer` is recursive....

Comment: I suggest you to add the complete block (right after the catch) and console.log there some text like - 'This is the last call'. This way you'll know if the subscribe ends by some mistake or not.

Comment: It does stop...it doesn't retry.....unless dataStream() is being called by something else repeatedly

Comment: Can you update your question to explain what `subscribe continues to retry over and over and over` this means and how it is seen during your tests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `await` to fetch data.

You can do like below :

```js
async dataStream(dataLayer): void {
    const postBody = JSON.stringify(dataLayer);
    try {
        const responce = await this.http.post('https://api.example.com/capture', postBody, {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          })
        });
        responce.subscribe(result => {
            if ( result === 'success') {
              this.setWindowDataLayer(dataLayer);
            }
        })
    } catch(error) {
        console.error('Failed to send dataStream: ', error);
        responce.unsubscribe(); //do unsubscribe here
    }
}
```

Comment: If I read this source code. I would be wondering what this Angular developer was doing, and if they've worked on an Angular project before.